# Why Don't the Azure Storage Capacity Metrics Show a Value?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Via the Azure portal I enabled minimal monitoring of blobs in an Azure storage account and added the Capacity and Container Count metrics in the Monitor tab.  I've waited a couple hours and don't see any values.  I thought that after an hour I'd have these values to help show me how much data I'm using.  From what I've read Verbose monitoring isn't needed.  Any ideas?  I'm just trying to see how many GB of blob storage I'm using.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is working as of the next day.  I had to change the view to 24 hours from the default last 6 hours to get anything to show.  Maybe this will help someone if they have the same issue.